# Limit of $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-((\log(\frac{x+a}{\sigma}))^\nu-(\log(\frac{x}{\sigma}))^\nu)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits

What is the value of $$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-((\log(\frac{x+a}{\sigma}))^\nu-(\log(\frac{x}{\sigma}))^\nu)}$$ where $\nu, \sigma>0$.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the notation a bit. Here's a sketch: By the MVT,

$$\tag 1 [\ln (x/b)]^p - [\ln ((x+a)/b)]^p = pc_x^{p-1}(\ln (x/b)- \ln ((x+a)/b))
$$ $$= pc_x^{p-1}\ln (x/(x+a)) = pc_x^{p-1}\ln (1-a/(x+a))),$$

where $c_x$ is between $\ln (x/b), \ln ((x+a)/b).$  As $x\to \infty,$

$$\ln (1-a/(x+a))) \approx -a/(x+a).$$

The term $c_x^{p-1}$ is no larger than a constant times a power of $\ln x$ for large $x.$ Thus it will be killed of by the $-a/(x+a)$ term. The limit in $(1)$ is therefore $0,$ hence the original limit is $e^0 = 1.$

Comment: Thanks "Harish" for nice solution. But could you elaborate your statement "The term $c_x^{p−1}$ is no larger than a constant times a power of $ln(x)$ for large $x$."

Comment: Hi, I'm not Harish. As for the estimate, we have $c_x$ between $\log x/b,\log (x+a)/b.$ Both of these terms are asymptotic to $\log x$ at $\infty.$ Hence so is $c_x.$ It follows that $c_x^{p-1} \sim (\log x)^{p-1}$ as $x\to \infty.$

Comment: I am sorry, Thanks "Zhw".

Comment: Does it nor depend on power $\nu$, means for $0<\nu<1$ its different and for $\nu>1$ its different.